# Angular export and import constants

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ES6 with Angular 1.4 and having an issue with exporting a constants file and importing into my angular module.

```
constants.js

export const MY_CONST = {
    CONSTANT_ONE: 'constant',
    CONSTANT_TWO: 'constant two'
}

index.js

import angular from 'angular';
import MY_CONST from './constants';

angular.module('myModule')
    .constant(MY_CONST, MY_CONST);
```

Some other code has been left out for brevity but this is the gist of my issue. When I run this example type code, I get this in the console:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
MY_CONSTProvider <- MY_CONST <- index
```

Thank you for helping me understand how I can export and import using ES6 and Angular 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first MY_CONST in the Angular.Constant call to be a string. For testing change it to "foo". The .constant call is a key value pair. You are passing a value into the key and the value. You need to pass a string key into the first parameter.